# What's the fastest way to find which coordinates are in a certain perimeter?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, gps, geolocation, coordinates

Let's say that i have a database of 100,000 coordinates,
i need to find which ones are less than 1 mile away from a certain coordinate.

What's the most efficient way to do this?(in any language)

Comment: Are your coordinates in Lat/Lon degrees or in x/y miles?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, we have to write a basic function to calculate the distance between 2 points:

```
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {}
```

For this example, I will base the function on the formula of a spherical earth projected to a plane ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance#Spherical_Earth_projected_to_a_plane))
Firstly, we have to calculate the deltas (the distance in degrees between the lat and longs) and the mean latitude (average of latitudes):

```
var dLat = lat1 - lat2;
var dLon = lon1 - lon2;
var mLat = (lat1 + lat2) / 2;
var earthRadius = 3959; //in miles
```

Then we convert those to Radians using `d=180/PI rad`:

```
dLat = dLat * 180 / 3.1415926535;
dLon = dLon * 180 / 3.1415926535;
mLat = mLat * 180 / 3.1415926535;
```

Now, we use the formula to transform our data into distance:

```
var distance = earthRadius * (dLat * dLat + Math.pow(Math.cos(mLat) * dLon, 2));
```

And return the distance

```
return distance;
```

Now, just iterating through all the points and checking if the distance is ok for each one. Let's say a point is described in this way:

```
var p = {
    lat = ...
    lon = ...
}
```

And assuming there is a list of points (for example, named points) and a reference point (for example, named ref).

```
var result = []
points.forEach(function (d) {
    if (distance(d.lat, d.lon, ref.lat, ref.lon) <= 1) {
        result.push(d);
    }
};
```

You can also check for latitude boundary box - longtitude requires more complex calculations and it's just a waste of time. You can determine a mile in degrees is `1/69 deg/mile` (approximately 0.1449 degrees). So you can check which points are outside of this boundary box:

```
var result = []
var maxLat = ref.lat + 0.1449;
var minLat = ref.lat - 0.1449;
points.forEach(function (d) {
    if (d.lat > maxLat || d.lat < minLat) continue;
    if (distance(d.lat, d.lon, ref.lat, ref.lon) <= 1) {
        result.push(d);
    }
};
```

Then you **should** finish with an array of points that are closer than 1 mile from the reference point.
I might have a mistake in the formula things (I'm more like a programmer than a mathematican). So double check if they work with the Wikipedia article I added a link to.

Comment: Would it not be faster to convert the 1 mile distance to a "degree distance", rather that converting each coordinates point? Let's say that 1 mile corresponds to a distance of 0.001 degrees, then we just have to check that `(d.lat - ref.lat)**2 + (d.lon - ref.lon)**2 < 0.001**2`, which requires less integer calculations. I may be wrong in my proposition, just asking.

Comment: For extra speed, you could do a simple "early-out" bounding box check based on min/max lat and long to discard most of the points and only do the expensive distance calculation for those that pass it.

Comment: @Delgan not exactly - a mile distance is different at different latitudes. For example - at latitude 38N/S - a degree of longtitude is 69 miles, while at latitude 90N/S - a degree of longtitude is reaching 0 miles.

Comment: @samgak yea, you are right. I should (and will) add it to my answer